# How to compare the value of a variable in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I want to display the `active` class if the title variable matches the name.
This is how I convey the meaning.

```
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{> header content=title}}

    {{{body}}}

    {{> footer}}
</body>
```

In the menu, if title is equal to a variable, display the class active

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <a {{#if title == 'Portfolio'}} class="active" {{/if}} href="/portfolio">Наши проеткы</a>
        <a {{#if title == 'Blog'}} class="active" {{/if}} href="/blog">Полезно почитать</a>
        <a {{#if title == 'Contact'}} class="active" {{/if}} href="/contact">Связаться</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a {{#if title == 'Ru'}} class="active" {{/if}} href="/ru">RU</a>
        <a {{#if title == 'Eng'}} class="active" {{/if}} href="/eng">ENG</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How to compare the value of a variable in handlebars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a {{#if (eq title 'Portfolio')}} class="active" {{/if}} href="/portfolio">Наши проеткы</a>
```